# apache servers won't start on MAMP with OS upgrade to Sierra

Tags: php, apache, mamp, macos-sierra

I just updated my OS to `macOS Sierra v 10.12.2`. And after doing this upgrade I can't get apache to start correctly with my [MAMP](https://www.mamp.info/en/) application for my local Wordpress site project. MySQL server starts and goes to green but Apache Server remains red.

I have tried to stop and restart apache from command line term, and also tried changing the password for my local DB in command line and within `/wp-config.php` file.

Any thoughts on what could have caused this and how to reconfigure for my OS sierra?

```
My-MacBook-Pro:~ myname$ httpd -v
Server version: Apache/2.4.23 (Unix)
Server built:   Aug  8 2016 18:10:45
```

Comment: I'm on the same version as you (OS & MAMP) and I've had no issues with my Mac since updating. Have you checked your Apache logs located in `/Applications/MAMP/logs`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Uninstalling 'Mamp' and -> **Reinstalling 'Mamp' ->** then -> **Reinstalling & configuring Wordpress CMS with new DB fixed this.** The only thing that worked for me, don't know why.